# Got only one huge file after solr index merge with IndexMergeTool

Tags: solr, indexing, lucene

Thanks for notice.

I'm a new one for solr, and I'm using the IndexMergeTool to merge solr index on 2 servers.

Indexes on server_1 has size 1.4GB with lots of files, and on server_2, the size is 380MB.

After my running:

```
java -cp /migration/lucene-2.9.1/lucene-core-2.9.1.jar:/migration/lucene-2.9.1/contrib/misc/lucene-misc-2.9.1.jar org.apache.lucene.misc.IndexMergeTool /tmp/newIndex /server_1/data/solr/data/index /server_2/data/solr/data/index
```

I got only one huge file:

```
$ ls -lah /tmp/newIndex/
total 1.5G
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Sep 24 08:08 .
drwxrwxrwt 9 root root 4.0K Sep 24 08:06 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1.5G Sep 24 08:08 _3.cfs
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  284 Sep 24 08:08 segments_2
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   20 Sep 24 08:08 segments.gen
```

Is it correct? If it will harm the performance when there is only one huge file like that?
Or is there any options for the tool that I can set it to generate multiple small files?

Thanks again for notice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Yes, it's expected behavior.
- No, it will not affect your
  performance, your index will be the same, just with more docs (but
  you do that for your needs, right?), so it's same as you will add more docs by yourself.
- No, there is no any options
  for **this** tool to generate small files.